# Correlate incidence rate with number of cases

Tags: correlation, poisson-regression, cross-correlation, epidemiology

As title says, I want to see how well incidence rate (over a period of years) of a disease compares with number of cases of a certain procedure (over the same period of years) used to cure it. How would this be done? Is Pearson's product moment appropriate?

Comment: You could use Poisson rate regression, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/300587/using-poisson-for-crime-rates and serach this site. Use the number of cases as a covariable.